# Does Prophet of Kruphix apply to Planeswalker abilities that create creatures?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

The [Prophet of Kruphix](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=prophet%20of%20kruphix) has the ability

> You may cast creature cards as if they had flash.

Does this apply to the Loyalty ability

> Put three 1/1 white soldier creature tokens onto the battlefield

of the Planeswalker [Elspeth, Sun's Champion](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=elspeth%2C%20sun%27s%20champion)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's no overlap here at all, for two reasons.

1. Elspeth doesn't involve casting creature cards. What goes on there has nothing to do with the process of casting creature cards.
2. Even if it did, you don't have anything that lets you use Planeswalker loyalty abilities on other peoples' turns.

Casting a creature card is the process you go through to put *Prophet of Kruphix* on the battlefield in the first place:

1. You take it from your hand.
2. You pay its costs.
3. The spell goes on the stack. (It's a creature spell, because the card has the creature type.)

That's the casting part. Hopefully, it doesn't get countered. When the spell resolves, the creature lands on the battlefield.

Sometimes it's a little different: a card with Flashback ([Ancient Grudge](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ancient%20Grudge)) can be cast from your graveyard rather than your hand. A card with Cipher ([Paranoid Delusions](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Paranoid%20Delusions)) has a free copy cast of it sometimes. But the process is still the same: the creature, or the spell, goes on the stack.

Elspeth's ability isn't the same thing. It's a loyalty ability and it's that ability that goes on the stack. When it resolves, it puts some creature tokens on the battlefield. The ability is used, but a spell isn't cast. Also, the tokens may get represented by physical cards, but they're still tokens and don't count as cards.

Comment: Okay, understood. I got both of these cards in booster packs, trying to maximize what I can do with them. Thanks!

Comment: You got a couple of _really_ nice cards. Congrats, and have fun.